# Jpeg order of encoded mcu blocks

Tags: jpeg

I am trying to encode raw yuv422 bytes from a camera to a jpeg file in c++. I have reviewed different source codes that do this. I am still having trouble understanding the order in which the compressed mcu blocks are placed into the jpeg file. What i would like to do is encode each block in a sequential pattern left to right top to down. What items in the jpeg file govern this (header parameters, zig-zag table...etc)? I presume there must be a parameter(s) becaue it doen't appear that the mcu blocks are always place in the same order, based on the different source codes that i have reviewed. If this is the case how would a jpeg decoder(reader) know the order of the mcu blocks.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MCUs are encoded left to right, top to bottom.

The zig-zag is within a block.